# Constrain to UINavigationController navigationBar anchors

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, constraints, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to constrain a view to be 100% like the `navigationBar` of a `UINavigationController`. The following isn't working…

```
view.addSubview(someView)

someView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    someView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.leadingAnchor),
    someView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.trailingAnchor),
    someView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.topAnchor),
    someView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.bottomAnchor)
])
```

But replacing *any* of the first three constraints to `view` makes `someView` visible. This for example works:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    someView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.leadingAnchor),
    someView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.trailingAnchor),
    someView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
    someView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.bottomAnchor)
])
```

Constraining to `tabBar` inside a `UITabBarController` on the other side works even when constraining everything to `tabBar`:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    someView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tabBar.leadingAnchor),
    someView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tabBar.trailingAnchor),
    someView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tabBar.topAnchor),
    someView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tabBar.bottomAnchor)
])
```

I'm fine with the workaround, but I wonder why it's not working when constraining to `navigationBar` alone. Is there a better way so that `someView` has the same size and position as `navigationBar`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add your subview as `view`'s subview and you set constraints just to `navigationBar`, they have no common ancestors as error you get says:

> 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors < NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:xxx "UIView:xxx.leading" > and < NSLayoutXAxisAnchor:xxx "UINavigationBar:xxx.leading" > because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal.'

... it looks like if you set at least one constraint equal to `view`, now your `someView` knows that it has something common with its superview `view` as well as with `navigationBar`.

One way to solve your problem would be if you just added your view to NavigationBar

```
navigationBar.addSubview(someView)
```

Note: I've tested your code and it doesn't work with setting constraints equal to TabBar's anchors